# activity indicator animation from cell selection

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I am woundering how I could show a activity indicator on a cell from the didselectCellFromIndexPath method?

basicly i want to start the activity indicator animation from the did select then once I get a return from my parsing class I would stop the animation and replace with a tick. but im not sure how to do this inside the didselectcell method? this is the code I would use.

```
cellActivityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        [cell setAccessoryView:cellActivityIndicator];
//then
[cellActivityIndicator startAnimating];
//then
[cellActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

but i just need some advice on doing it inside indexPath:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, you can access the cell itself using:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Initialise, add to cell's view and start your activity indicator

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        //Call your function or whatever work that needs to be done
        //Code in this part is run on a background thread

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            //Stop your activity indicator
            //Code here is run on the main thread
        });
    });
}
```

This method uses libdispatch/Grand Central Dispatch and requires you to have iOS 4 or greater.

Comment: That concluded a two day search and much trial and error - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("Downloading image", NULL);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/2441/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/step0-edu-pricing?wid=264&hei=144&fmt=png-alpha&qlt=95"];

    cellActivityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [cell setAccessoryView:cellActivityIndicator];

    NSData *downloadedImage = download data;

    // update your UI screen
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [subViewActivityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
        [cell setAccessoryView:something];
    });
});
dispatch_release(queue);
```